# get all ids from string

Tags: php, regex

Hi All
i have the following string :

```
$sortable='record_69#record_83#record_70##'
```

how i can get all numbers(id) from that $sortable string?
i try to do somthing like this:

```
preg_match_all('[0-9]', $sortable, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
     print_r($result);
```

but the result is Array ( [0] => Array ( ) ) 
i wnat $result to be like $result[0]=69......

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern `[0-9]` takes **only one** number. You want to select more than one, so you have to use a quantifier :

```
preg_match_all('/record_([0-9]+)#/', $sortable, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

You also need to add delimiters (/ in this case), and parenthesis to capture the numbers.

Comment: you'll need to put the + inside the parentheses

Answer (score 0):

preg_match_all('[0-9]+', $sortable, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$sortable = "record_69#record_83#record_70#";
preg_match_all("/(\\d+)/", $sortable, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```